# How to display date in PHP?

Tags: php, date

If date now is 2015-08-15. How to display the result like this:

```
2015-08-15

2015-08-16

2015-08-17
```

I have the following code:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$a = "3";
$nextDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today . ' + ' . $a . ' days'));

echo $nextDate;
```

Comment: if it were d-m-Y sequence they would sort easily

Comment: Do you want sorting dates or just display like in question? I mean you have a data with unsorted dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date = new DateTime();

echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . '<br/>';

for ($i = 1; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $date->modify('+1 day');
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: I was glad to help ;)